# Alternative to SwingWorker or how to implement it in this case...?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, swingworker

I have hundreds of different functions that run in the EDT. A great deal of them include long-running tasks and some include changes to the GUI. Occasionally the GUI hangs for users but it is hard to keep track of all the locations this happens due to the GUI hangs not happening in the same areas 100% of the time. The issue is not high priority because the hang usually starts working after a minimize/maximize of the window, but it needs to be done eventually.

After some research I discovered I could use doInBackground() under [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) for any methods with labor-intesive work and use done() for GUI drawing. Also I believe I can use [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for every GUI drawing that happens to be in the doInBackground() function. However, I want to avoid adjusting every one of the hundreds of functions in my code.

Is there a way I can use a single SwingWorker and send any long-running methods to the doInBackground() function? Using the invokeLater function multiple times for every misplaced GUI code where a SwingWorker would be used is **not** a problem as it is not that frequent.

If this is not possible is there some kind of alternative I can use? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

All methods that update the GUI must be invoked on the EDT, otherwise you may end up with some unexplained GUI behavior (which sounds like what you are seeing). You could have repaints that don't happen properly, thread races, etc.

It is not advised to run long running tasks on the GUI because they will cause the GUI to become unresponsive, so for long running tasks, SwingWorker is a good solution to use (note that the process and done methods are called on the EDT automatically so your worker can do its long running work in doInBackground but you can safely update the GUI without using SwingUtilities.invokeLater from the done method).

As you mentioned you have hundreds of methods and you don't want to call SwingUtilities.invokeLater every time, you might want to look into one of the task frameworks. The Swing Application Framework was developer under JSR-296 http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/swingappfr/ but is not actively supported, but still provides a nice framework.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_Application_Framework is a list of alternative frameworks.

It sounds like you are going to need to do some significant rewriting in your application. Calling GUI methods from outside the EDT is unsafe to do.

Comment: I think I have written part of the question incorrectly. I want to avoid rewriting all long-running tasks in those methods with SwingWorker and would like to be able to have a single SwingWorker that will work with all the methods.

Using SwingUtilities.invokeLater multiple times is **not** a problem because it wouldn't happen too often.

I'll edit my post and fix the communication error.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot reuse the same SwingWorker multiple times.

Comment: Alright, I'm going to have to add SwingWorkers to every method seperately. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how what your asking would be possible. Swing has no way of knowing of what would qualify as a "long running" method call before execution. If the method is already being executed (on the EDT) Swing can't simply pick it up and move it to a new thread. Even if you would indicate which method calls should be run in background threads pulling it off would be hard. The only way I can think of to make this possible in Java is with AOP (you could intercept the method calls). But implementing [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) would be harder then reimplementing your existing application to use SwingWorkers.

It sounds like the architecture of your Swing application is broken. Long running tasks must not be executed on the EDT. I'm sorry but I think you just have to bite the bullet on this one. If you want your application to feel snappy, responsive and have predictable behavior you will have to fix this by putting the long running code in background threads.

If your application uses a lot of background tasks you might want to use the excellent [Swing Task API](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=268). Otherwise you will find yourself in a SwingWorker spaghetti quite fast.

> for every GUI drawing that happens to be in the doInBackground()

You can't call Swing drawing, updating, etc. methods in the 'doInBackground()' method (well actually you can, but you must not do that). This is because this is the method which gets executed off the EDT. GUI drawing and component updates must only be called in the 'done()' method of a SwingWorker.

Comment: Hmm, well it looks like I'm going to have to stick with adding SwingWorkers to everything. I was hoping there would be another way. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with this answer.  As you are reworking things consider making your own extension of SwingWorker.  For example, I have an interface Busiable, which various components of my app implement to put a busy animation up over the top of whatever parts of the GUI make sense.  This typically uses JLayer/JXLayer.  Inside AppSwingWorker, it starts the busy animation and stops it when the doInBackground is complete.  Another useful thing my AppSwingWorker does is to wrap done() and call get() to make any exceptions during doInBackground() bubble up, then it has default behavior to log the error.

Comment: And yet another thing to read up on is Java 7 [SecondaryLoop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SecondaryLoop.html).  Not much documentation out there yet on it, but it might be useful to you.